# How can i make my ubuntu 19 installation successful?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, vmware-workstation

Excuse my English. I am trying to set up a ubuntu vm using workstation 15. While I was installing the program this messaged popped up. My desktop is about 10 months old, and I don't know why this is happening. [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bszY.png)

Comment: Installing what program? This doesn’t look like a Ubuntu installation at all. This looks like an already running system.

Comment: Could you add more detail about versions and what else you did?

Comment: This was the tutorial I was using: https://theholmesoffice.com/installing-ubuntu-in-vmware-player-on-windows/

I downloaded the 19.04 versions, saved it to downloads, created a new vm, and entered in my information. Here is a link to my settings: https://imgur.com/a/MZsLWcF

Another issue I have been dealing with is whenever I enter fullscreen mode, I find black bars along the sides of the screen. I have looked through other posts, but I still could not get it work.

Comment: Have you verified the ISO is not corrupt, as per the message?  Tried downloading the ISO again?  Black bars on the screen is a separate issue (you need to install the VMTools), you should post a new question regarding that one you've successfully installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu installation is very easy on VMware workstation, where first you need to download the Ubuntu ISO file and configure a virtual machine to [install and use virtual environment with Ubuntu Operating System](https://linuxconcept.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-16-04-in-vmware-workstation/).

You can [install Ubuntu in VMware Workstation](https://linuxconcept.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-16-04-in-vmware-workstation/) using these 10 steps:

Step 01: Create a New Virtual Machine

Step 02: Select Hardware Compatibility

Step 03: Use or select Ubuntu Image to install

Step 04: Configure Virtual Machine Name and file Location

Step 05: Configure Virtual processor for new virtual machine

Step 06: Setup Virtual RAM memory for new virtual machine

Step 07: Setup Virtual Machine Network

Step 08: Configure Virtual storage disk for new virtual machine

Step 09: Now power on of the virtual machine after finish the VMware setup

Step 10: Get the Ubuntu setup screen on display

follow the given instruction on [LinuxConcept](https://linuxconcept.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-16-04-in-vmware-workstation/) and it will install in 10 min.

Answer (score 0):

This is a later post (just saw it).  Download Ubuntu V20.04 LTS from the Ubuntu site. The default is 64-bit.  Ensure (in BIOS) Hardware Virtualization is enabled.  Set and restart if you change it.

Then Ubuntu 18 LTS and Ubuntu 20 LTS both work very well in VMware Workstation V15 and now V16.

Ubuntu 18 ISO ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64 is 2,082,816,000 bytes and Ubuntu 20 will be near the same.

I have Ubuntu 18 running and upgraded to 20 in place.

Try the above as it is working.